# Jquery $.post method doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Background: I'm using Apache with XAMPP to set up localhost.
I'm relatively new to programming, and very new to PHP. I'm trying to call a PHP file in the same directory as my Javascript file, but the code I'm using doesn't seem to work. Here's a sample:

Javascript:

```
function SendPhps(){
var point = 2;'
$.post('json.php',point);}
$(document).ready(function(){
SendPhps();
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
file_put_contents('example.txt','Itworks');
}
?>
```

EDIT: Ok, I've revised my scripts to be more simple, but opening my page still doesn't trigger any alert box:

PHP:

```
<?php
    if (empty($_POST))
        echo "empty";
    else
        echo "not empty";
?>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var point = {'param':2};
    $.post(
        'json.php', 
        point, 
        function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the apache user has write permissions on `example.txt`?

Comment: The ending bracket to `SendPhps` is not there. You also have a stray quotation mark.

Comment: You edited your post to add a `'` after `2;`... why? @David it's at the end of line 3.

Answer (score 1):

Your var point needs to have a more meaningful structure than that.  What does '2' mean to a post?  Nothing really.  Give it a name.  i.e.

```
     var point = {'html':2};
```

and since you're just learning, don't try to do multiple things at once like writing to a file.  Keep it simple.  Just have your PHP echo your result.

Here is an example on jsfiddle using their 'echo/html' URL - which simply echos out whatever value you set to the 'html' parameters.

http://jsfiddle.net/k5ygv/

Comment: Ok, I tried your scripts, but I still don't get any alerts when I open the page.

Comment: See the link I added.  I have to change the 'param' to 'html' because that's what the URL is expecting.  But in any case, it shows how the $.post() function is working.